# One central place for a list of data which is used in the Model, View, and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model

Right now in a MVC4 app we are using a hard-coded list (of the months) to generate CSS-classes on the view, and also use another hard-coded list in JavaScript with the same values to bind jQuery to the CSS-classes which then call a controller method which binds it to the `Month` enumeration model which corresponds to the same two lists as in the JavaScript and view. I.e.:

Month enumeration:

```
[Flags]
public enum Month
{
    NotSet      = 0,        /* 0b000000000000 */
    Januari     = 1 << 0,   /* 0b000000000001 */
    Februari    = 1 << 1,   /* 0b000000000010 */
    Maart       = 1 << 2,   /* 0b000000000100 */
    April       = 1 << 3,   /* 0b000000001000 */
    Mei         = 1 << 4,   /* 0b000000010000 */
    Juni        = 1 << 5,   /* 0b000000100000 */    
    Juli        = 1 << 6,   /* 0b000001000000 */        
    Augustus    = 1 << 7,   /* 0b000010000000 */    
    September   = 1 << 8,   /* 0b000100000000 */
    Oktober     = 1 << 9,   /* 0b001000000000 */
    November    = 1 << 10,  /* 0b010000000000 */
    December    = 1 << 11   /* 0b100000000000 */
}
```

HTML/Razor:

```
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";

    var months = new List<string>(new[] {    "september",  "december",     "maart",    "juni", 
                                             "oktober",    "januari",      "april",    "juli", 
                                             "november",   "februari",     "mei",      "augustus"});


    foreach (var month in months)
    {
         <div class="@string.Format("{0}", month)">
             @month.ToUpper()
         </div>
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var months = [ 'januari', 
               'februari', 
               'maart', 
               'april', 
               'mei', 
               'juni', 
               'juli', 
               'augustus', 
               'september', 
               'oktober', 
               'november', 
               'december' ]

months.forEach(function(month) {
    $('.' + month).bind('click', function() {

        $.get('/MyController/Edit/' + month, function(data) {
            //Do something
        });
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(Month month) // Month is the enum of above
    {
       // Do something
       return View();
    }
```

A friend stated that it is a sin to not get the information from the months from the Model and hard-code it on the view.

The reason this is done is that the CSS-classes need to be bind in a particular order and that the HTML/Razor arranges this in that way. And furthermore, I do not know how to replace the JavaScript `months` values with values that come from the model.

I was wondering what your opinion is on the matter. Should there be one central place where the Month names are listed? And if so, how do I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your Month enum values doesn't correspond to actual months you could simply assign the with values that correspond to your order. For exmaple:   `September=1, December=2` and etc.

Then you can get your months in a correct order by using something like:

```
var months = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Month)).Cast<Month>().OrderBy(m => m).Select(m=>m.ToString());
```

Your model will contain:

```
public class Model
{
   public IEnumerable<string> Months { get; set; }
   public string MonthsSerialized {
      get 
      {
          //Newtonsoft json*
          return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Months);
      }
   }
}
```

[*Newtonsoft json](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

HTML/Razor:

```
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";

    foreach (var month in Model.Months)
    {
         <div class="@string.Format("{0}", month)">
             @month.ToUpper()
         </div>
    }
}
```

Javascript (in the same View):

```
var months = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.MonthsSerialized)');

months.forEach(function(month) {
    $('.' + month).bind('click', function() {

        $.get('/MyController/Edit/' + month, function(data) {
            //Do something
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I find it a bit ugly to place the JavaScript in the view, so I will try the data-helper of the other answer. The order by will be a bit difficult, but there must be logic in starting at september and skipping three till finished,

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I think your friend is right. You can create a helper that puts it in the DOM. For example:

```
<div id="months" data-months="['januari',...]"></div>
```

Then you can read months in javascript through the data API.

In C#, you can enumerate an enum like:

```
foreach (var month in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Month))) { ... }
```

There is also the capability to extend enumerators in C# so you can specify order. I will let that be a programming challenge for you.